# Finding basis for intersection of these 2 spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following two subspaces and am asked to find a basis for the intersection of them.

$$W_1=u\in \cal{R}^5:u_1+u_3+u_4=0,2u_1+2u_2+u_5=0$$
$$W_2= u\in \cal{R}^5: u_1+u_5=0,u_2=u_3=u_4$$

To find a basis, I set up the following matrix by making all 4 of the conditions hold
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 &0&1&1&0\\2&2&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0&1\\0&1&-1&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
When I rref this matrix I get
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

So I am unsure if the columns of this reduced matrix are a basis for my intersection.  I expect that the vector (0,1,1,1,0) would be in it because of the condition u2=u3=u4, but I am not completely sure

Comment: The equations $u_2=u_3=u_4$ are not correctly translated in the matrix.

Comment: that would make sense.  Should I have u2 = u3, u3=u4 instead as seperate equations?

Comment: Yes, what you have now is $u_2 = u_3 + u_4$.

Comment: So once I edit my matrix and add the two, if I RREF it, will the columns be my basis vectors?

Comment: @yankeefan11: No, you will have an equivalent system of equations. To have a basis of the intersection, you must solve the system of equations.